# take Json NSDictionary items into strings-Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

I am a bit new to Objective-c . I am trying to parse json data which looks like this which is in a single array.

```
[{"id":"3672","name":"TestName","color":"red","cost":456","date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]
```

below is Objective C part of code

```
 FullUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.com?user=%@",uservalue];
 NSString *absoluteURl=[NSString string];
 absoluteURl=[self URLEncodeString:FullUrl];

 NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:absoluteURl];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:nil error:nil];

 NSData *jsonData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSDictionary *parseJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil]
```

Now i wanted to know how can i take each key value into a string from parseJson ?. for example I want name value into "Stringname" etc.,

When i put a breakpoint at line NSDictionary *parseJson =    and take curser over parseJson it shows like

```
 <__NSCFArray 0x1dddb670>(
{
    name = "TestName";
    id = 3672;
    color = red;
    cost = "456";
    date = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
}
)
```

So it means , json parsing is working fine in my code ? Why  the order is not correct when compare to json webservice Items order .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON object is an array of dictionaries. Dictionaries are unordered sets of name/value pairs so they will not remain necessarily be in the same order they are initialised in.

---

So Suppose your response is like that:

```
data:[{"id":"3672","name":"TestName","color":"red","cost":456","date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]
```

Try it like this:

```
NSArray* dataArr = [parseJson objectForKey:@"data"];

for(NSDictionary *obj in dataArr){

NSString* Stringname = [obj objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString* Stringid = [obj objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString* Stringcolor = [obj objectForKey:@"color"];
NSString* Stringcost = [obj objectForKey:@"cost"];
NSString* Stringdate = [obj objectForKey:@"date"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An JSON object is an unordered set of name/value pairs so it will not remain in same order as initialised.

use

```
NSString* Stringname = [parseJson objectForKey:@"name"];
```

to access elements in dictionary

Comment: I didn't edit it :P I said in a comment that this won't work because parseJson is an array

Comment: Yeah correct , objectForKey is specific for NSDictionary  and Xcode is showing warning that it is  not for NSArray .

Answer (score 1):

The order is not the same because you items are mapped in a `NSDictionary` which is a unordered collection.

And yes, the json parsing returns the right result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's working fine,
Elements in JSON can have order,
but NSDictionary elements are not ordered.

So when JSON string is converted to NSDictionary,
order is shuffled.